# Eclipse linking .so can't find .so.4

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries

I am using the primesieve library from here http://primesieve.org/ in eclipse. After I installed the library I can link and run my code from the command line but when using it in Eclipse it gives "error while loading shared libraries: libprimesieve.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". I have linked to the actual library (libprimesieve.so) which is in the same folder but for some reason it can't find the .so.4. How do I get eclipse to see the .so.4?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a wrong library path configured in eclipse: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_general_pns_libpath.htm